# Create No to nearest Decimal in filemaker calculation

Tags: logic, filemaker

I have database where i am calculating the shipping cost. The logic of shipping cost is such way that it is calculated every 500gm. I have price list according to different weight but when i am using calculation taking the weight from user for example 1.4 i am unable to get it to next calculative weight of 1.5 , .7 to 1.0 , 1.7 to 2.0 how to achieve this?

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you have a price list by weight, you don't need to round the weight entered by the user - just lookup next lower or next higher, or use the < relational operator.  If you do need to round the number, provide a better explanation of your rounding rules. "*Every 500gm*" does not rhyme with "*nearest decimal*".

Comment: Kapil, could you show us the calculation and price list you're already using? It would help shed some light on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (substitute myNumber to get a different result):

```
Let ( 
[
   myNumber=2.6;
   myNumberInt = INT(myNumber);
   myNumberFr = myNumber - myNumberInt;
   myNumberFr = Case ( myNumberFr =0;0;myNumberFr >0.5 ; 1;0.5 );
   result = myNumberInt + myNumberFr
]
; 
  result
)
```

You can wrap it in a custom function, in case you need to change it later throughout the system.

I am sure there is a better mathematical formula, but this should get you started

Comment: I believe you could have written all of that as just `.5 * Ceiling ( 2 * myNumber  ) `. But this does not produce the "nearest decimal".

Comment: I knew, there is a shorter formula! it is not to a nearest decimal, but from the original post and sample input/output this looks like that Kapil needs. You should post it as an answer if confirmed by op

Comment: "*this looks like that Kapil needs.*" It doesn't look that way to me. But I don't really understand his question.

Comment: @michael.hor257k this ceiling function in calculation field does the trick thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is fixed.

I have price list according to weight slab in different table.
I used the Country code with Zone id to track prices for particular weight slab prices provided by the courier company.

The price list for e.g. is in such way :- 
Zone 1 .5Kg 100Yuan 1.0Kg 120 yuan etc etc , there goes till 20Kg in some case at max.

so when i input the weight in weight field for e.g. 13.5kg i use this weight / .5 which gives me a value 27 , the reason i use to divide the weight with .5 is for example if i input the weight to  13.8 kg i get 27.6 there upon i embed this in ceiling function in calculation field which gives me value of 28 which i can use to calculate the next price slab in the price list which is for every 500Gms +- .

Once i get this done i use this in script which does the job of going to particular layout to search the zone and the prices and retrieving those data to original layout to show the desired result.

Regards,

Soni

Comment: `weight / .5` = `2 * weight` -- And all of this (calculation, script, etc). is not necessary if you use a [lookup](http://www.filemaker.com/help/14/fmp/en/html/relational.12.20.html).